# Loading file from assets folder to webview

Tags: android, html

I'm trying to load a html file in my webview using this codes. but is show Webpage not available

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.frux.web.R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/www/webpage");
    } 
}
```

I already edit my codes into this but still webpage not available

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("file://android_assets/www/index.html");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just mistype the assets. It should be **"asset"** without "S".

Answer (score 0):

The file should be extension with html

The easiest way would probably be to put your web resources into the assets folder then call webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/filename.html");

try this will help you...

Comment: but my file name is only index and don't have .html

Answer (score 0):

`web.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/www/webpage");`

webpage is a folder or a file?  I guess it should be

`web.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/www/webpage/file.html");`

or

`web.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/www/webpage.html");`

Answer (score 0):

Write below line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
web.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/www/webpage/index.html");
```

instead of

```
setContentView(com.frux.web.R.layout.activity_main);
web.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/www/webpage");
```

Comment: @user1545096 Are you give the internet permission in your android manifest file?

Comment: Please add this uses-permission in your android manifest file before application tag. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Webpage not available. That's what the browser say

Comment: There is 3 Slash after "file:///" and are you giving the internet permission?